# Own payment method in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I want to add non gateway payment method other than of check.

As per my current scenario, I have my own payment server (other than of any payment gateway/check option) where I want to send the request for any product payment.

The only thing that is source which is getting nil. so do we any better way to achieving this scenario.

Comment: Which payment gateway are you using?  Is it a payment gateway supported by spree_gateway (https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway)?  If not, is supported by ActiveMerchant (https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant)?